# Golang Gorilla Mux server local package import and not used issue

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm testing a simple server app with Gorilla Mux. I keep getting undefined error when running the app. This is the structure of the app

```
src/ptest/
├── app
│   └── app.go
└── main.go
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "ptest/app"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Testing App")
    app := App{}
}
```

**app.go**

```
package app

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
}

func (A *App) Run() {
    fmt.Println("Listening at :8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", A.Router))
}
```

As you can see, I have a `main` that initialized `app` by importing from `ptest/app`. But I am getting an error when I `go run *go`:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:5:2: imported and not used: "ptest/app"
./main.go:10:9: undefined: App
```

This is my `go env`. I am wondering if something not right with my environment?

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/haha/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/haha/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
```

Comment: This is covered in Chapter 1 of the "Basics" section of the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `App{}` struct by package name. Your are importing the package but not using it. `App` struct is declared in `app` package. that's why the error.

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:5:2: imported and not used: "ptest/app"
./main.go:10:9: undefined: App
```

In your program you are trying to initialize an `App{}` which does not exist in `main.go`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "ptest/app"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Testing App")
    app := app.App{}
}
```

It is well described in Golang Spec for [Qualified Identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers):

> A qualified identifier is an identifier qualified with a package name
>   prefix. Both the package name and the identifier must not be blank.

```
QualifiedIdent = PackageName "." identifier .
```

> A qualified identifier accesses an identifier in a different package,
>   which must be imported. The identifier must be exported and declared
>   in the package block of that package.

```
math.Sin    // denotes the Sin function in package math
```